# how to get multiple values from different tables plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I usually do this query every day:

```
select * from table1
where name = 'PAUL';

select * from table2
where id_user = 012345;

select * from table25
where name = 'PAUL';

select * from table99
where name = 'PAUL';

select * from table28
where id_user = 012345;
.
.
.
```

I do this query every day. Today is 15 tables, tomorrow maybe 20, the only change is the name or id of the user to search. I have to go placing the username or id in each of the queries, so I need a query where there is a variable and assign the name and id.
    .
    .
There is a way to simplify this query and make it better? Such as:

```
DECLARE
l_name  table1.name %type;
l_id_user table28.id_user %type;
BEGIN
l_id_user := 012345;
l_name := 'PAUL';

select * from table1
where name in ('l_name');

select * from table2
where id_user in (l_id_user);
.
.
.

END;
```

I tried that way but fails. I need this query because in most cases need to see up to 20 tables or more.

Comment: Your original SQL script looks simple and good. Why do you think it's not ? Do you need to process the data somehow or is this just a visual check ? Based on provided information I'd say adding PL/SQL makes it just more complex without any other benefits. It's hard to say anything else as you don't describe what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hello @user272735 please see the post again, I explained the situation better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is an easy way to repeatedly run a sequence of select statements in SQL*Plus - but with varying criteria you can do it like this:

```
ACCEPT l_name PROMPT "Input user name: "
ACCEPT l_id_user PROMPT "Input user id: "

select * from table1
where name = '&l_name';

select * from table2
where id_user = &l_id_user;

select * from table25
where name = '&l_name';

select * from table99
where name = '&l_name';

select * from table28
where id_user = &l_id_user;
```

In a pl/sql block `declare ... begin .. end;` select statements behave differently from when you run them stand alone in SQL*Plus:

- They won't automatically print output.
- You must use e.g. a `FOR LOOP` or a variation of the `SELECT INTO` syntax to capture the result for subsequent processing. You should seek some documentation on pl/sql programming.

You should understand that pl/sql is definitely not designed for screen output.

It is possible to print out string values using `dbms_output.put_line`, but you are completely on your own with regards to formatting a row of values into a suitable string.

If your result contains more than a few columns formatting for screen output becomes very cumbersome as you wont have any formatting utilities like the java `String.format()` to assist you.

And if your result contains more than one row you have to provide some sort of loop construct allowing you to print out the individual rows.

Conlusion:

These are the drawbacks of pl/sql - I really don't see any benefits - unless your aim is to apply some logic to the data being read rather than just printing it to the screen or a file.

Comment: Do you know any way to do with PL/SQL? @Jens-Krogsboell

Comment: I didnt find the way to make it better @JensKrogsboell

Comment: What do you expect to benefit from doing it in pl/sql as opposed to the sql*plus suggestion I already gave in my answer?

Comment: I have added to my answer some thoughts on the use of pl/sql for this task.

Comment: Hello, it works in plsql:

    select * from table1
    where name = (upper('&var1')); --varchar

    select * from table28
    where id_user = &var2; --number
    .
    .
    .
When I run this code I just have to put the value of the variables in the prompt.

This way I can use the same code to find multiple users in different tables without placing data in each SELECT statement. @JensKrogsboell